# Print max value with data

Tags: python

i want to get data with highest value.

```
class Mountain:

    def __init__(self, name, height):
        self.name = name
        self.height = height

mountain_01 = Mountain("Mount Everest", 8850)
mountain_02 = Mountain("Mount Kazbek", 5033)
mountain_03 = Mountain("Vinson Massif", 4892)
mountain_04 = Mountain("Kilimanjaro", 5895)

highest_mountain = max(mountain_01.height, mountain_02.height, 
mountain_03.height, mountain_04.height)
print(f"Highest is : {highest_mountain}")
```

i expect output as "Highest is: Mount Everest 8850"

Comment: and what actually happened?

Comment: it prints only 8850

Comment: Yes!  That is because your variable `highest_mountain` just holds the number that is the result of the max() calculation.  It has no linkage to the mountain objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start by capturting all your mountains in a list, and then calculating [max](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) over that list, by using the key as the height of the mountain

```
#List of mountains
mountains = [mountain_01, mountain_02, mountain_03, mountain_04]

#Get highest mountain based on height of mountain
highest_mountain = max(mountains, key=lambda mountain:mountain.height)

print(highest_mountain.name)
print(highest_mountain.height)
```

The output will be

```
Mount Everest
8850
```